# tag cloud from database

Tags: database, tags, cloud

I store tags in a table which is entered by users of my site.  So basically I just need to run,

```
<?php echo $thing->tags; ?>
```

and this will return all the tags for that thing.  Right now it just spits out a list of the tags like "bananas apples fruit, blueberries", where the tags are both comma and space delimited.  I know that in order to create a tag cloud I need to spit out the tags to a ul and then run a jquery script on the li's.  I think if I can get my tags to appear in the form,

```
<ul>
<li>bananas</li>
<li>apples</li>
<li>fruit</li>
<li>blueberries</li>
</ul>
```

Then I will be able to write a jquery script to put each of these elements in little tag cloud boxes.  But I don't know how to get the tags to appear in this form.  When I echo the tags can I apply some php function which will do this for me?

UPDATE:  I used preg_split,

```
<?php $tags=preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "$things->tags"); var_dump($tags);?>
```

And now they are listed in an array -- comma and space delimited.  My only challenge now is to surround these elements of the array in li tags.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this one out on my own.  After creating the array as mentioned above, I used

```
<?php foreach ($tags as $row) : ?>
<li><? echo $row[0]; ?></li>
<li><? echo $row[1]; ?></li>
<li><? echo $row[2]; ?></li>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

etc.